# pyspark : convert date from this format dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: date, pyspark

Could someone help me out with this:

I am trying to convert date like 10-Jun-2018 09:59:51 to 2018-06-10 in spark but not getting any success
Basically i am querying a date field from an external table like:

```
select format_datetime(my_date, 'y-M-d') as dt from blahblah
```

The above works in Athena but not in pyspark.

I used the below code in pyspark but getting an empty string

```
select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as dt from blahblah
```

Note: my_date is of string data type in the external table and i need to extract the date part to create a partition on this field.

I appreciate any help in this regard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in `hive` and `spark-sql` as well

**Pyspark**

```
sqlContext.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('10-Jun-2018 09:59:51', 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')").show()
```

**HIVE**

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('10-Jun-2018 09:59:51', 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) for the hive builtin date time UDFs.

And [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) for the timestamp formatting strings.